# Animate text with left slide effect

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I am trying to create a text slide effect. An example would be to transform `TS` to `TextSlide`such that:

- `T` would slide to the left and as it slides `ext` would show
- S to stay where it is, but `lide` to slide out to the right.

Any idea of how to do that?

```
   TS
T-->S--->
TextSlide
```

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9svL5nu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/j3p8L8g7/

CSS:

```
.one, .two, .three, .four {
display: inline-block;
}

.two, .four {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var oldWidths = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {

    oldWidths[0] = $(".two").width();
    oldWidths[1] = $(".four").width();

    $(".two").css("width",0);
    $(".four").css("width",0);

    $("#button").click(function(){
        slide();
    });

});

function slide(){
    $(".two").animate({
        width:oldWidths[0]
    },1000);
    $(".four").animate({
        width:oldWidths[1]
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you want:

```
    <marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>

<marquee direction="up">This text will scroll from bottom to top</marquee>

<marquee direction="down" width="250" height="200" behavior="alternate" style="border:solid">
  <marquee behavior="alternate">
    This text will bounce
  </marquee>
</marquee>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: please take a look at the jsfiddle in the question

Comment: This is an animation for it: http://jsfiddle.net/g9svL5nu/3/  If you want a fancier animation, you can do what's shown above, or something I asked about weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact code for you:

CSS:

```
.one, .two, .three, .four {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.one{
    left: 400px;
}
.four{
    left:-60px;
}
.two{
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.one').animate({left:'0px'}, function(){
      $('.two').fadeIn('slow');
      $('.four').animate({left:'0px'});
   });
});
```

Comment: This is close to what I am after, though it isn't quite right. Was this your final result? http://jsfiddle.net/g9svL5nu/2/

Comment: Yes, can you let me know what change you want in above result, I will update it as per..!!